# Issue with websites not scaling to fit on a mobile screen

Tags: html, css

I used http://reddit.com's website as a reference to build a css webpage where the side bar always remains the same size on the page, while the whole left side shrinks gradually when the screen does.

```
sidebar{width:400px;float:right;/*rest doesn't matter*/}
leftside{width:auto;height:auto;;overflow:hidden;/* no float */} // i think this
// is where i missed up, reddit's site didn't have this
```

Anyways, this site won't scale at all on a mobile device, the sidebar takes up the entire screen, but on reddit's site it scales nicely. How can I make my site scale? Do i need another div to wrap the side and the left side? I tried to look this up online, but everyone just said to not use px to define the side bar, but reddit used px and it still scaled...

Thanks

Comment: reddit has a different mobile style entirely. But what you want is a "responsive css framework".

Comment: whoa really? Whenever I browse their website it appears that it's just desktop, there is no mobile/desktop option

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang: you don't get redirected to it but it can be accessed via http://i.reddit.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If on mobile device the thing scale its probably due to a media queries that use the screen size because on my browser reddit act the same as your description and the side bar take the whole browser size when i resize it down to the size of a mobile device.
if you want it not to act like reddit does on browser you can eighter; use media queries along with the width of the browser and resize the side bar in these rules or; use some sort of javascript or html5 and css to set the side bar into a button and make it expand to the whole screen when OnClick

Comment: How do media queries work? I've never heard of those when using CSS? Do you mean width:em or width:%?

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang: see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ for tips on using media queries.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use responsive css framework such as http://foundation.zurb.com/ or http://gumbyframework.com/